# Change fmu step size after export

Tags: solver

I am currently working on a Co-Simulation with fmi. In addition, I want to optimize the solver step size of exported FMUs. It is possible to change the step-size of FMUs after the Export?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to change the solver step size of exported FMUs without reexporting again as its impossible to change after binary is built unless the importing tool has such options.